# Electron app Travis CI builds fail

Tags: build, continuous-integration, electron, travis-ci, xlib

I'm using Electron to build a cross-platform app using javascript. I'm having some trouble getting Travis CI to build succesfully though.

The [docs on setting it up](https://electron.atom.io/docs/tutorial/testing-on-headless-ci/) say that my `.travis.yml` should look similar to this:

```
addons:
  apt:
    packages:
      - xvfb

install:
  - export DISPLAY=':99.0'
  - Xvfb :99 -screen 0 1024x768x24 > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

My current `.travis.yml` looks like this:

```
language: node_js

node_js:
  - "node"

addons:
  apt:
    packages:
      - xvfb

before_install:
  - cd src/

install:
  - npm install

before_script:
  - export DISPLAY=':99.0'
  - Xvfb :99 -screen 0 1024x768x24 +extension GLX +extension RANDR > /dev/null 2>&1 &

script:
  - npm test
```

And here is a build log (in a pastebin because it's huge): https://pastebin.com/8N4P2S7Y . The important part is below:

```
> ThemeCreator@0.1.0 test /home/travis/build/blabel3/ThemeCreator/src
> electron .

Xlib:  extension "RANDR" missing on display ":99.0".
Xlib:  extension "RANDR" missing on display ":99.0".


No output has been received in the last 10m0s, this potentially indicates a stalled build or something wrong with the build itself.
Check the details on how to adjust your build configuration on: https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/common-build-problems/#Build-times-out-because-no-output-was-received

The build has been terminated
```

Thank you guys so much for any help you can provide!

Answer (score 1):

It should be possible to run xvfb with just `sh -e /etc/init.d/xvfb start`

Currently I'm using the following config and it works fine.

```
os:
  - linux

language: node_js

node_js:
  - "7.7"

before_script:
  - if [[ "$TRAVIS_OS_NAME" == "linux" ]]; then export DISPLAY=:99.0; fi
  - if [[ "$TRAVIS_OS_NAME" == "linux" ]]; then sh -e /etc/init.d/xvfb start; fi
  - if [[ "$TRAVIS_OS_NAME" == "linux" ]]; then sleep 3; fi

script:
  - node --version
  - npm --version
  - npm install
  - npm run e2e
```

Comment: You could also use ```xvfb-run my_script``` to cut down on some of the setup. 
http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/man1/xvfb-run.1.html